# Android HEX Colors

Tags: android

I many places Android requires HEX colors, like 0X31515724. How can i convert colors like  #3399ff to this ? Is there any website or tool that would allow be to convert color codes to the required values.

Comment: Where does `Android requires HEX colors`?? And you want a _code Or a tool_ to convert it?

Comment: I want  to convert #xxxxx to the 0Xxxxxxx format ?

Comment: Could you give us an example? Represent a color in the two formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append FF at the start of your #3399FF, and it makes 0xFF3399FF

Components are :

- Alpha (FF by default in many apps/contexts)
- Red (33)
- Green (99)
- Blue (FF)

On the other way, your 0X31515724 is the #515724 color, with an alpha of 0x31 (49/255=19%)

Comment: Is `0xFF3399FF` a Hex format color?

Comment: That's the way they can be defined in Java code (as Integers). In XML resources files, they are often noted as #RRGGBB or #RGB or #AARRGGBB or #ARGB

Comment: That's doesn't mean they are Hex. Even the word `Hex` is not mentioned anywhere in Android [Color doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)!. Hex (although I don't know what it is in this context) is different than a `4-bytes packed-ints`.

Comment: What are your talking about ? "Hex" just mean that you are displaying your color components with hexadecimal digits... Or did I miss something ?

Comment: `mean that you are displaying your color components with hexadecimal digits`. Then how you explain that `#515724` have many ways to be displayed? `#00515724`,`#01515724`, `#02515724`, ...?

Comment: To sum it up: `#3399FF`, `#FF3399FF`, `#003399FF` are different colors as far as Android concerns.

Comment: No, #3399FF is the same as #FF3399FF (by convention, it's an opaque color, so alpha=FF)

Comment: TOTALLY Right. It is convention but not Hex format.

Comment: Ok, but can you give us you definition of Hex format ? What's the difference ?

Comment: If you say it is Hex, this means it has a unique equivalence in the other format. `#3399FF` is equal to `#FF3399FF` as we agreed on. Then what is the unique equivalences to `#FF3399FF` and `#003399FF`?! this is the issue I'm talking about.

Comment: I just want to know how i can convert #3399ff to an int value. In  the java code i want to send the back ground color, that takes an integer value of the format 0Xxxxxxx. How can i do this ?

Comment: @user365019 : just answered this in the first line of my answer... ;)

Comment: @iturki The heck? Hex isn't a particular format. Hexadecimal only means the particular base the digits are in. It has nothing to do with the ordering of ARGB.